# Карьер, карьер и карьера

Tags: заимствования, омонимы

Понятно, что слово "карьер" — иностранного происхождения. Но интересно, что этим словом обозначаются совершенно разные понятия. Карьер — горная выработка, карьер — аллюр лошади и карьера — продвижение по служебной лестнице.
Почему так?

Answer (score 1):

КАРЬЕР. Заимств. в начале XIX в. из франц. яз., где carrière < ср.-лат. quadraria "место для обработки камня", суф. производного от quadra "четырехугольник, кирпич".

КАРЬЕРА. Заимств. в первой половине XIX в. из франц. яз., где carrière "карьера" < "самый быстрый ход лошади" — из итал. carriera — тж. < "путь экипажа", суф. производного от carro "телега, повозка" (см. карета).

Из этимологического словаря Шансова.

Возможно, карьер(а) (аллюр лошади) и карьера (продвижение по служебной лестнице) слова с общей этимологией. Карьер (горная выработка), имеет другую этимологию, и похоже на два верхних слова только по звучанию.